# How get all keys in redis using php redis?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am using https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis  extension to access redis. I want to get all keys in redis from PHP code.
I tried following code:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$allKeys = $redis->keys('*');
print_r($allKeys); // nothing here
```

But following command in shell giving results:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
"kq92p7b5tf63tmk12v54373e03 hs7ep4lc2m6ci5kk5dosgpelg4 
pt7lfejenqbmmovjpmp9aojuf0 2p05gf20or6r5ee5i7sts90kn1 
cb1d6g3d3bvqetjfmkmaurmpp3"
```

I am able to set key and data in following manner from PHP script:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->set(session_id(), json_encode(array('uname'=>'messi fan')));
```

How to get `KEYS *` from redis using phpredis ?

Comment: Have you found a way to get all keys using phpredis?

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are doing it correctly: `$redis->keys('*')` retrieves all the keys.

The result:

```
"kq92p7b5tf63tmk12v54373e03 hs7ep4lc2m6ci5kk5dosgpelg4 
pt7lfejenqbmmovjpmp9aojuf0 2p05gf20or6r5ee5i7sts90kn1 
cb1d6g3d3bvqetjfmkmaurmpp3"
```

is in fact the key that you set when you did:

```
 $redis->set(session_id(), json_encode(array('uname'=>'messi fan')));
```

So `session_id()` returned the value:

```
kq92p7b5tf63tmk12v54373e03 hs7ep4lc2m6ci5kk5dosgpelg4 
pt7lfejenqbmmovjpmp9aojuf0 2p05gf20or6r5ee5i7sts90kn1 
cb1d6g3d3bvqetjfmkmaurmpp3
```

therefore this became the name of the key that you set.

Answer (score 4):

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('xxxxxx', 6379); // use your Host from Redis desktop Manager - connection
$redis->auth('xxxxxx'); // use your Auth from Redis desktop Manager - connection
$allKeys = $redis->keys('*');
print_r($allKeys); // nothing here
```

Comment: The post included your proposed solutions and it didn't work.

Answer (score -9):

Try this

```
 $redis->get('key');
```

Comment: $redis->keys('*'); Will get you all the keys